# Distribution of $Y$ if $P(Y = X) = P(Y = 0) = 1/2$ with $X$ exponentially distributed?

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X > 0$ be an exponential distributed random variable and $Y$ be the random variable with $P(Y = X) = P(Y = 0) = 1/2$. What is the distribution of $Y$?

I first thought that $Y$ would be Bernoulli distributed, but this doesn't make much sense considering the fact that this would lead to $E(Y) = X/2$ and $V(Y) = 1/4$, which seems odd. Is it actually uniformly distributed?

Comment: **The hypothesis does not suffice to determine the distribution of $Y$**. For example, if $Y=BX$ with $P(B=1)=P(B=0)=\frac12$ and $B$ independent of $X$ then the distribution of $Y$ is the sum of one half of a Dirac mass at $0$ and one half of the distribution of $X$. But if one chooses $x$ such that $P(X>x)=\frac12$ and then defines $$Y=X\mathbf 1_{X<x}$$ then indeed $P(Y=X)=P(Y=0)=\frac12$ but the distribution of $Y$ is rather different since $P(Y<x)=1$.

Comment: Thanks! So I wouldn't even be able to calculate the expected value here? Guess the excercise is given wrong then.

Comment: If the authors really write "and $Y$ be **the** random variable with" then one cannot answer their question and they should be chastised for asking incorrectly their problem, using the absurd **the**. If they add the condition "$Y=BX$" stated in my comment, then one can answer their question.

Comment: I guess you're right by defining $Y = BX$. But how would I calculate the expected value now? I can't even tell whether $Y$ is discrete or not.

Comment: Neither discrete nor continuous, obviously. But if $B$ and $X$ are independent then $E(BX)=$ $___$ hence you are done.